# error on compile custom rom i tried compile android for my device but nothing working

Tags: android, makefile, clang, android-source, lineageos

I need help i tried to compile a custom rom because of the error i already did the compilation environment i downloaded a docker with build envirolviment and i tried in several ways to get around until using clang 
`/lib64\" HOSTCC=/home/build/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc HOSTCXX=/home/build/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-g++ -C kernel/motorola/sanders O=/home/build/android/out/target/product/sanders/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=\"/home/build/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-\"` `CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=\"/home/build/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-\" CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CC=\"/usr/bin/ccache clang\" modules; fi )" make: Entering directory '/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders' make[1]: Entering directory '/home/build/android/out/target/product/sanders/obj/KERNEL_OBJ' /home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders/Makefile:692: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler ccache: error: Could not find compiler "clang" in PATH CHK include/config/kernel.release GEN ./Makefile CHK` `include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h CHK include/generated/utsrelease.h Using /home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders as source for kernel CC scripts/mod/empty.o ccache: error: Could not find compiler "clang" in PATH make[3]: * [/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders/scripts/Makefile.build:266: scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 1 make[3]: Waiting for unfinished jobs.... CC scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s ccache: error: Could not find compiler "clang" in PATH make[3]: [/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders/scripts/Makefile.build:153: scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s] Error 1 make[2]: [/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders/scripts/Makefile.build:410: scripts/mod] Error 2 make[2]: Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make[1]: * [/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders/Makefile:556: scripts] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/build/android/out/target/product/sanders/obj/KERNEL_OBJ' make: *** [Makefile:150: sub-make] Error 2 make: Leaving directory '/home/build/android/kernel/motorola/sanders' 23:16:25 ninja failed with: exit status 1`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use code tags to format the error message, this will make it easier for others to read and understand your problem. Also it would be helpful if you could give more details on how you set up your build environment and which commands you used for building.